# Error while installing neo4j ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, neo4j

When I run `'gem install neo4j'`

I get this error:

```
While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    malformed format string - %)
```

What does that mean?? Is there a problem with the source of the gem?  Does this happen to anyone else?
I just installed rvm today, could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

`jruby -S gem install neo4j` worked for me, from https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted#installing-and-using-ruby-gems

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to install neo4j successfully...

What version of Ruby are you using? To check in the terminal, write:

```
$ which ruby
```

I'd highly recommend using jRuby for neo4j as that's the platform it works best with (Neography uses neo4j's REST API instead of native java bindings).

If you use RVM:

First update, RVM:

```
$ rvm get head
```

Next find and install the newest* stable jruby:

```
$ rvm list known | grep jruby

jruby-1.2.0
jruby-1.3.1
jruby-1.4.0
jruby-1.6.5.1
jruby-1.6.6
jruby-1.6.7.2
jruby-1.6.8
jruby[-1.7.4]
jruby-head
```

- The rubies listed will surely be outdated before for too long. Install the latest stable version (1.7.4)

  $ rvm install jruby-1.7.4

Now switch to jruby:

```
$ rvm use jruby
Using /path/to/jruby-1.7.4
$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_40-b43 +indy [darwin-x86_64]
```

Last but not least, install neo4j:

```
$ gem install neo4j
```

Or install with a Gemfile and Bundler:

**Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'neo4j'
```

**Install**

```
bundle install
```

Don't forget to switch to jRuby each time you open a new terminal window.

Hope this helps, I'll update the answer if you can let me know what version of ruby you're using or some more details on the issue.

One last thing...

Use OracleJDK/JRE for Java, **do not use** OpenJDK/JRE it's not supported by Neo4j and is reported to have some issues. They mention this in quite a few different places (mailing lists, issues, etc).